How would I skip test compilation in a MySQL build?
As the title suggests, I am building MySQL version 8.0.37 from source on a Linux machine and would like to skip test compilation.
I have attempted adding the flag:
-DINSTALL_MYSQLTESTDIR=

which, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_install_mysqltestdir , should '... suppress installation of this directory.' The directory is still being installed.
Could it be a position dependent flag? The only flags prior to this in my call to cmake are -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 and -DWITH_BOOST=/path/to/boost/.
How does one avoid building the test files ? I have not been able to find explanations online.
I am building on the Raspbian OS, which is a fork of Debian 'Bookworm'.
